# Evaluar el valor de una variable para convertirlo en una variable

Tags: javascript

Esta es una linea dentro de un for en con jQuery append:

```
<span id="TITLE'+i+'" 
      class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">'
    +$(".card-title").attr("id")
+'<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>'+
```

Cuando `i=1`, quiero que se resuelva la parte de

```
TITLE'+i+'
```

con el valor de esa variable (por ejemplo, que evalúe el valor de `TITLE1`, `TITLE2`, etc.). Y lo mismo en la parte donde está el texto del span, es decir en:

```
$(".card-title").attr("id")
```

que sea tomado **como una variable** y tome el valor que corresponde a la variable `TITLE1` en JavaScript.

> Vi que en PHP se puede con algo parecido a `$$Nombre_de_Variable`, pero no sé acá cómo logro hacerlo.

Si alguien me puede ayudar o conoce alguna alternativa se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata con esto:

```
var variable = eval($(".card-title").attr("id"));
```

`$(".card-title").attr("id")` devuelve TITLE1 como cadena, eval evalúa la expresión que se le pase en forma de cadena, entonces si hay una variable que se llama TITLE1 debería devolver su valor como resultado de evaluar la expresión

Comment: `$(".card-title").attr("id")` devuelve TITLE1 como cadena, eval evalúa la expresión que se le pase en forma de cadena, entonces si hay una variable que se llama TITLE1 debería devolver su valor como resultado de evaluar la expresión

Comment: Buen aporte @JhonPedroza, No lo encontraba en ningún lado y justo era lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por su aporte, su colaboración fue útil y encontré la Respuesta.
Exactamente la función eval() era lo que necesitaba.

```js
var tam = 2;
var jqRow = jQuery('.row');
var pretitle = "TITLE";
var title = "";
var TITLE1 = "My First Project";
var TITLE2 = "My Second Project";
for (i=1;i<=tam; i++){
  title = pretitle + i;
  jqRow.append('<span id="' + eval(title) +'" class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">' + eval(title) + '<i class="material-icons right"> more_vert</i></span><br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así

```js
var tam = 5;
var jqRow = jQuery('.row');
var pretitle = "TITLE";
var title = "";
for (i=1;i<=tam; i++){
  title = pretitle + i;
  jqRow.append('<span id="' + title +'" class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">' + title + '<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span><br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: Exactamente es esto, ya lo he probado antes, pero lo que sucede es que ese TITLE1 Solo se muestra como VALOR.. Y No es reconocido como una variable ni muestra el Valor que existe en la variable TITLE1, Porque existe una variable traída de un txt que dice por ejemplo: TITLE1="My Firts Post"; y lo que debe mostrarse al final es: My First Post